Parallelize for-loop in pyspark; one table per iteration
I've got a few dozen spark tables in Databricks with sizes between ~1 and ~20 GB and want to execute a function on each of these tables. Since there is no interdependency between the results of each query, this should be easy to parallelize.
However I have no idea how to instruct pyspark to perform the following code in parallel. It just proceeds table after table.
This is a simple demo to show the structure of my code:
Cell 1 (create some demo tables):
tables = []
columns = list("abc")
for i in range(10):
    nrows = int(1E6)
    ncols = len(columns)
    data = np.random.rand(ncols * nrows).reshape((nrows, ncols))
    schema = ", ".join([f"{_}: float" for _ in columns])
    table = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
    tables.append(table)

Cell 2 (perform an operation on each of them):
quantiles = {}
for i, table in enumerate(tables):
    quantiles[i] = table.approxQuantile(columns, [0.01, 0.99], relativeError=0.001)

Note: The demo is a bit simplified. In reality I have different columns on each table, so I can't just concat them.

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def run_io_tasks_in_parallel(tasks):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        running_tasks = [executor.submit(task) for task in tasks]
        for running_task in running_tasks:
            print(running_task.result())

# Replace with actual logic.
def process_table(table_name):
    return table_name, spark.sql(f"select count(*) from {table_name}").collect()[0][0]

table_names = ['A', 'B', 'C']

# Flatten the list of lambda functions before passing it to the executor
tasks = [lambda x=name: process_table(x) for name in table_names]

run_io_tasks_in_parallel(tasks)

EDIT: Modified the example with provided sample code. Hope this helps.
import numpy as np

tables = []
for i in range(10):
    columns = list("abc")
    nrows = int(1E6)
    ncols = len(columns)
    data = np.random.rand(ncols * nrows).reshape((nrows, ncols)).tolist()
    schema = ", ".join([f"{_}: float" for _ in columns])
    table = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
    tables.append(table)

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
quantiles = {}

def run_io_tasks_in_parallel(tasks):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        running_tasks = [executor.submit(task) for task in tasks]
        for running_task in running_tasks:
            index, result = running_task.result()
            quantiles[index] = result

def process_table(index, table):
    return index, table.approxQuantile(columns, [0.01, 0.99], relativeError=0.001)

# Flatten the list of lambda functions before passing it to the executor
tasks = [
    lambda x=index, y=table: 
    process_table(x, y) for index, table in enumerate(tables)
]

run_io_tasks_in_parallel(tasks)


can't you just use parallelize?
Each element of the list tables should be a PySpark DataFrame, created using the spark.createDataFrame
# create a RDD of the tables
# `sc` a.k.a. SparkContext should be already created once you started the session in Databricks
rdd_tables = sc.parallelize(tables)

# apply the function to each table in parallel
rdd_quantiles = rdd_tables.map(compute_quantiles)

quantiles = rdd_quantiles.collect()

you can then first create a list of dataframes then use parallelize and map functions.

Looks promising - but leads to an error during sc.parallelize(tables)
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: PySparkRuntimeError: [CONTEXT_ONLY_VALID_ON_DRIVER] It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063
Well, I don't really see what I would be nesting here ‍♂️

can you try to create a list of NumPy arrays and schemas and see the result?

Not sure what you mean - a list of what? schema for each table? And then what to do with it? ... In the meantime been trying on manual parallelization via SparkContext.runJob to no avail :-/

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

I know what a numpy array is. I still don't see how it will help me with my problem in parallelizing the function call on several tables.
